# Concatenate geometry shader output

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, geometry-shader

I have a problem with geometry shader output vertices concatenation. I'm using openGL 3.3 and QT 5.6. I'm using lines_adjacency layout for GS and I make rectangles via each line. Like that:
[line strip to rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1pnb.png)

But the problem is I can't concatenate output primitives. Like that:
[line strip with adjacency to rectangels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kalTA.png)

But I have done it by using adjacency, so I can't do that for more than three lines(4 points).

Comment: "*But the problem is I can't concatenate output primitives." Why can't you? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I can, for example, in case of straight line(3 points), I can generate rectangle and another one for next line, but finally I'll have 8 vertices, instead of 6.

Comment: 3 vertices are not enough to make a line when using adjacency rendering. You have to provide at least 4 vertices.